# Exposing local dockerised app using nginx docker container

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, julia, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a julia app which has been dockerized using below docker file. And,I am running this local `app` as docker container on port `8080`. The goal is to expose this docker app (port 8080) to public using nginx docker container.

I have followed this tutorial: https://www.domysee.com/blogposts/reverse-proxy-nginx-docker-compose and based on the instructions I have created two files, `docker-compose.yml` and `nginx.conf` as shown below.

Dockerfile for the local-app:

```
FROM julia:1.6

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gcc
ENV JULIA_PROJECT @.
WORKDIR /home

ENV VERSION 1
ADD . /home

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["julia", "-JApp.so", "-t", "auto", "-L", "src/App.jl", "-e", "App.run()"]
```

Docker-Compose:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: production_nginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - .:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./nginx/error.log:/etc/nginx/error_log.log
      - ./nginx/cache/:/etc/nginx/cache
      - /etc/letsencrypt/:/etc/letsencrypt/
    ports:
      - 8080:80
      - 443:443

  local-app:
    image: local-app:latest
    container_name: production-local-app
    expose:
      -  "8080"
```

Nginx.conf:

```sh
events {

}

http {
  error_log /etc/nginx/error_log.log warn;
  client_max_body_size 20m;
  
  proxy_cache_path /etc/nginx/cache keys_zone=one:500m max_size=1000m;

  server {
    server_name app.local.hosting;

    location /local-app {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
      rewrite ^/local-app(.*)$ $1 break;
    }

    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.local.hosting/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.local.hosting/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
  }
}
```

However, running the docker-compose starts two containers, `1` app and `2` nginx, but nginx exits with some error. May I ask, what could be the potential cause of the service failure. Look forward to all the suggestions, thanks in advance!

**Update:**

Adding the output from terminal upon executing the docker-compose file:

```sh
user@user:~/Desktop/App$sudo docker-compose up
Starting production-local-app  ... done
Starting production_nginx      ... done
Attaching to production_nginx, production-local-app
production_nginx | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
production_nginx | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
production_nginx | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
production_nginx | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: IPv6 listen already enabled
production_nginx | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
production_nginx | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
production_nginx | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
production_nginx | 2021/12/05 16:27:03 [emerg] 1#1: open() "/etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:23
production_nginx | nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:23
production_nginx exited with code 1
production-local-app | 
production-local-app |  Web Server starting at http://localhost:8080 - press Ctrl/Cmd+C to stop the server.
```

Comment: How do you start containers? If you use -d flag, remove it and you will see the output from both containers starting up. Alternatively, run docker compose logs nginx to see if you can spot the problem in the log.

Comment: Thanks @jabbson for the response, highly appreciate it! 
I am running `docker-compose.yml` file using docker-compose which starts both the containers as presented in docker-compose file. however, the local app seems to be running but the nginx service fails.

Comment: As per the documentation, and with reference to my docker compose file, it should start two containers `1. nginx` and `2. local-app`.

Comment: Do you see any logs on the screen from the nginx server, when running docker-compose up without `-d` flag?

Comment: @jabbson I have updated the question with output of the docker-compose.

Comment: Well, the reason for the nginx not to start is its configuration `(/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:23)` mentions the file that doesn't exist `("/etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)`. Are you trying to run your server over HTTPS?

Comment: Logs are so cool!

Comment: @jabbson I did create a SSL cert using certbot but the for now I am okay with running server over HTTP but for longer run it would be better if this can be run on HTTPS :)

Comment: My personal recommendation would be to start small and grow as you go as opposed to trying to build a intergalactic spaceship (so to speak) from the start. I've built the most basic example [here](https://github.com/jabbson/q70235941), try to run it and see if it works for you and then adjust your setup accordingly.

Comment: @jabbson, indeed thanks for the advice and the working example. I shall build up from here and will update on the progress!

Comment: You are very welcome and good luck.